# how to add line numbering to treeview?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, treeview

I need to read the excel file and display separate columns of data from it in treeview. in the first column I need to display the line numbering, but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\main7.py", line 57, in 
> treeview.heading("Index", text="#")
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1299, in heading
> return _val_or_dict(self.tk, kw, self._w, 'heading', column)
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 298, in _val_or_dict
> res = tk.call(*(args + options))
> _tkinter.TclError: Invalid column index Index

here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def select_excel_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx *.xls')],
        title='Select Excel File'
    )
    if filepath:
        clear_treeview()
        df = pd.read_excel(filepath)

        selected_columns = ['Column1', 'Column3', 'Column5']  
        df = df[selected_columns]

        treeview["columns"] = ["Index", *selected_columns]
        for column in treeview["columns"]:
            treeview.heading(column, text=column)

        for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), start=1):
            treeview.insert("", tk.END, values=[i, *row[1:]])


def clear_treeview():
    for item in treeview.get_children():
        treeview.delete(item)


root = tk.Tk()

select_button = tk.Button(root, text="Select Excel File", command=select_excel_file)
select_button.pack()

treeview = ttk.Treeview(root)
treeview.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=treeview.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
treeview.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

treeview.heading("Index", text="#")
treeview.column("Index", width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of "Index" I used index 0 for the first column. but I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\main8.py", line 57, in 
> treeview.heading(0, text="#")
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1299, in heading
> return _val_or_dict(self.tk, kw, self._w, 'heading', column)
> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 298, in _val_or_dict
> res = tk.call(*(args + options))
> _tkinter.TclError: Column index 0 out of bounds

Comment: You don't need to call the two lines just before `root.mainloop()` as you haven't specified the columns when creating the treeview.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your message. [english is not my first language]

Comment: I means that you do not need to call the two lines: `treeview.heading("Index", text="#")` and `treeview.column("Index", width=50, anchor=tk.CENTER)` (before `root.mainloop()`).